# Multiple Check-outs Error!! must remain locked because its file type prevents multiple checkouts

Tags: tfs, unlock, locked, vcs-checkout, multiple-checkout

I try to check-in excel document regarding my development. But my build is failing because of its file is locked by me. But the problem is; when i select unlock the document, I am getting this error below.

```
> The item $/../../Device must remain locked because its file type
> prevents multiple checkouts.
```

I couldn't unlock this file. Because it is binary. I've tried to delete remote work space but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

When you have binaries files which you want to check it in, 
then you have to uncheck the box "Preserve pending changes locally during shelve your pending changes.

Because binary files cannot be merged that's why there are always locked.

After uncheck this box, my build was successful!